# Loop animation in Raphaël JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, raphael

This is a simple animation in the JavaScript library of Raphaël JS.
The function draws a field, then puts out the object of a pink rectangle.
When you hit the "gray" button the pink rectangle starts to move horizontally. The pink rectangle moves and once it hits its destined position it stops.

What I need help with is:

1: Make the pink rectangle return to its starting position.

2: Loop the animation so the pink rectangle goes back and forth.

I have tried to solve this by adding "x: 0", after the "x:-1" but without success. As you can see I've also set the repeat to infinity, also without success.

The field:

```
var p = Raphael(0, 0, 240, 140);
    p.rect(0,0,240,70);
```

The trigger button and function from onclick:

```
p.rect(130, 80, 50, 25)
    .attr({
        fill : "grey",
        "stroke-width" : 1
    })
    .click(function(){
    pinkRect.animate({
        repeat: "Infinity",
        x:-1,
        }, 2000);

});
```

Comment: A fiddle would be great to help on

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I've tried several times to get it to work in fiddle. But it just won't. Is it anyway to upload the live code?

Comment: what problem you are facing in uploading it to fiddle??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I don't get the animation to show up after hitting run. I chose "raphael 2.0" as extension, but no sign of work.
Anyway, here is all the code I use in this project: https://jsfiddle.net/j747g5a0/

Comment: thats because you were loading your `fiddle` in `https` whereas `Raphael` was loaded in normal `http` which is not allowed and thus the request to load `Raphael.js` was blocked. Well just remove `s` from `https` and try loading it again!! you will get!! let me check what I can do!!

Comment: Yeh, now I can tell! Thanks!:D

Comment: Is that the complete code you have got?? No html?? only javascript!! The way you have presented in fiddle is wrong!! you need to separate `js`, `html` and `css` in fiddle!! See **[this link](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/j747g5a0/1/)**. I just separated your js. similarly add any html if you have.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao , the button furthest to the right, is suppose to stop the animation and reset position. Is it possible that you could give me some lead there as well?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I copy and pasted everything from dreamweaver. So that's how it looks :P

Comment: That jus doesn't work or help even if you provide fiddle!! you need to create the exact replica of your problem in fiddle as the way you have to! Then its more understandable!! :)

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you want me to do . I have downloaded the raphael-min.js file from their homesite, and as you see in fiddle, that's the way that I see things and where all the code are placed in my dreamweaver and live preview. Looks exactly the same.

Comment: ok.. You see 4 different consoles in fiddle?? `html`, `css`, `js`  and `result`. Just paste your relevant code there, like, `js` code in `js` console, excluding that `script` tag, `html` code in `html` console excluding all those `html`,`head`,`title`,`body` tag etc., Hope you understood!! :)

Comment: When I try, it does not work. Can't you see the objects in result? http://jsfiddle.net/j747g5a0/5/

Comment: I can see but that's not the proper way to do it!! Anyways!! i'll try my best to solve it!!

Comment: Am sorry to say but your fiddle cannot be edited because of the reasons I previously mentioned!! try adding some code in the place where you have already placed your code!! you will find some warnings!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j747g5a0/6/

There you go. But now nothing shows.

Comment: yeah!! Even I tried that too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the callback function of the animate method, and make it call itself, as you effectively have 2 animations. So the key bit is the 2nd bit below...

```
p.rect(130, 80, 50, 25)
    .attr({
        fill : "grey",
        "stroke-width" : 1
    })
    .click( animPink );

function animPink() {
    var x = pinkRect.attr('x') < 0 ? 150 : -1;
    pinkRect.animate({ x: x }, 2000, animPink);
};
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j747g5a0/10/) click 3rd grey box

Comment: Thanks a lot, works 100%. Had no idea that you needed to create a variabel for it. Oh well, learned something new:)

May I ask if you could help me out with one more thing? The forth button with the ID of id="4", I want it onclick to paus and reset the animation of pick rectangle.

Comment: Also, I saw that you had answered my post here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001620/raphaeljs-animation-loop
The question is the same tutorial as this one, but raphael JS has like almost zero tutorials and few places where I can ask questions and get help, so could you please help me out with it? I've been stuck on it for quite some time and I want to make progress.

Comment: Not sure that you necessarily have to create a variable, but it feels simpler that way. Regarding the other question, I thought in the comments it says its working.

Comment: Could you help me out with the last fourth button as well please? I want the button id 4 to pause and reset the animation/position of the pink rectangle. That would be great!